# Get URLs with IP address from MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName() instead of localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localhost, ipv6

I am using MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName() to get a List of URLs and return them to the front end. Following is the example output where in i am getting domain in the form of localhost:

[
http://localhost:8081/files/1800_tiger.jpg/slideshow, http://localhost:8081/files/1800_trees.jpg/slideshow
]

Instead of localhost I want MvcUriComponentsBuilder to return me IP address of my system. Following is my code implementation:

```
     @CrossOrigin
     @RestController
     public class ContentResource {


        @RequestMapping("/getAllFiles")
        public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getAllFiles(@RequestParam String panelName) {
            List<String> fileNamesList = panelFileListMap.get(panelName);
            if (fileNamesList != null) {
                List<String> allFiles = fileNamesList.stream()
                        .map(fileName -> MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                                .fromMethodName(ContentResource.class, "getFile", fileName, panelName).build().toString())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(allFiles);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("No images are uploaded in category = " + panelName);
            }
        }


 @GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}/{panelName}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable("filename") String filename,
            @PathVariable("panelName") String panelname) {

        Resource file = storageService.loadFile(filename, panelname);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(file);

    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution myself: changed the getAllFiles method like following:

```
InetAddress ip = null;
@RequestMapping("/getAllFiles")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getAllFiles(@RequestParam String panelName) {

        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> fileNamesList = panelFileListMap.get(panelName);
        if (fileNamesList != null) {
            List<String> allFiles = fileNamesList.stream()
                    .map(fileName -> MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromMethodName(ContentResource.class, "getFile", fileName, panelName)
                            .host(ip.getHostAddress()).build().toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(allFiles);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No images are uploaded in category = " + panelName);
        }
    }
```